# Show that either G is abelian or the centre $Z(G) := \{z \in G|gz=zg, \forall g \in G \}$ has order |Z(G)| = 3.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a multiplicative group of order 27. Show that either G is abelian or the centre $Z(G) := \{z \in G|gz=zg, \forall g \in G \}$ has order |Z(G)| = 3.

I use Lagrange Theorem to show that Z(G) as a subgroup can either have order 1,3,9, or 27. I can eliminate 27 if G is not abelian, since there is bound to be one element not in Z(G) but I don't know how to eliminate others.

Comment: Hint: if $G / Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: In a p- group (here p=3) order of $Z(G)>1$

Comment: i can't really see how does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G/Z(G)$ is cyclic $\Rightarrow G$ is abealian. This eliminate the case $|Z(G)| = 9$. For the case $|Z(G)| = 1$, use class equation.

Comment: what is class equation?

Comment: here is a link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class you can find it any abstract algebra book, e.g. Dummit & Foote.

Comment: ok i don't quite understand why |z(G)| = 9 can be eliminated when G is abelian

Comment: $|Z(G)| = 9 \Rightarrow |G/Z(G)| = 3 \Rightarrow G/Z(G)$ is cyclic $\Rightarrow G$ is abelian $\Rightarrow G = Z(G).$